# How to Filter by Custom Field in Fishpig?

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

There is a way to get all the checked checkboxes of a custom field in Magento/Wordpress(with Fishpig extension):

```
$post->getCustomField($customfield)
```

I'm trying to filter the posts by selected checkboxes, and I'm considering to compare the filters to the posts via for loop, but is there a more efficient way of filtering posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom collection of posts that are filtered by a custom field:

```
$posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->addMetaFieldToFilter('custom_field_name', 'custom field value')
    ->load();
```

This will return all published posts that have the value 'custom field value' for the custom field called 'custom_field_name'.

Once you have a post model, the correct way to retrieve a custom field value is with the following:

```
$customFieldValue = $posts->getMetaValue('custom_field_name');
```

Comment: So I can get the posts or custom posts, but when I want to filter custom posts by "addMetaFieldToFilter('custom_field_name', 'custom field value')" it returns a null collection. I've accounted for lowercase/uppercase, but I can't retrieve posts with 'cell_type' that has the checkbox value 'RNA'. I've even tried addMetaFieldToFilter('cell_type, array('RNA' => 'RNA')) but still returns null. What do you think? And thank you!

Comment: Change ->load(); to ->load(true); and the SQL will be printed to the screen. This should help see what the query is actually doing.

Comment: if i have a custom field of select type(ie) drop down) , then my custom_field_name is 'type' and wat will be my 'custom_field_value' ??  I have my select drop down values like articles: Articles, something: Something

Comment: The code doesn't get the choices but it does get the selected values. You will have to write your own code to get the choices.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->load();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->getId() . '<br/>';
    echo $post->getPostTitle() . '<br/>';
    echo $post->getMetaValue('your_custom_field_name') . '<br/><br/>';
}
```

This code gets all posts and displays the post ID, post title and the value for the custom field that has the bame of 'your_custom_field_name'